# How to change the Initiator of a flow within a flow in Corda?

Tags: corda

I have 2 Nodes say Party A and Party B. I am hitting an API through Party A's node with some data then I need to process(Inside a flow) this data and create a State say State A(Party A will be the participant) then I need to Initiate another flow with the processed data(from the first flow itself) and party B as Initiator. So how will I do this? . Basically What I need to do is like I need to initiate 2 flows of different initiators inside one API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of `sendAndReceive`. In `Responder` class, which will be Initiated by the second party can make use of the data that send from the `MainClassInitiator`, which will be initiated by first Party.

```
    class MainClass {
        @InitiatingFlow
        @StartableByRPC
        open class MainClassInitiator(val ParameterFromApi: DataType,
                                      val NodeB: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
            @Suspendable
            override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

                val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

                val initiator = NodeB

                val session = initiateFlow(initiator)
                val initiatorValue = session.sendAndReceive<SignedTransaction>(ParameterFromApi).unwrap { it }
            }
        }

        @InitiatedBy(MainClassInitiator::class)
        class Responder(val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
            @Suspendable
            override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

                val request = session.receive<DataType>().unwrap { it }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can We use multiple responder class?

Comment: I think we can't use. but can call multiple times.